# Не отображается картинка

Tags: java, javafx

```
     String image = getClass().getResource("font2.jpg").toExternalForm();
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + image + "'); " +
            "-fx-background-position: center center; " +
            "-fx-background-repeat: stretch;");
```

> апр. 20, 2021 8:46:38 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$ImageCache getCachedImage
> WARNING: Error loading image: file:/C:/Android/Arkanoid/out/production/untitled3/sample/font2.jpg

Как можно установить фон приложения javafx? Пробовал использовать стили css, такая же ошибка

Comment: ошибки есть какие-нибудь ?

Comment: апр. 20, 2021 8:46:38 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$ImageCache getCachedImage
WARNING: Error loading image: file:/C:/Android/Arkanoid/out/production/untitled3/sample/font2.jpg

Comment: Если картинка лежит в resourses добавьте слэш / перед адресом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Как можно установить фон приложения javafx? Пробовал использовать стили css, такая же ошибка*

Лично я делал через SceneBuilder, добавляешь ImageView а под ним все остальные элементы. Если из кода, то тоже самое, изображение должно быть под всеми элементами, т.е в самом начале стека children

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]